# How to search a substring using values from another column and then delete row, Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, substring

Using VBA, I would like to know how to search for a substring within column A using a list of words from another worksheet, if a match is found I would then like to delete the cell.

Currently it will only delete cells with an EXACT match. I would like to be non-case sensitive and find partial strings.

```
Private Sub RemoveBusinessesButton_Click_OLD2()
    Dim Firstrow As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim Lrow As Long
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim ViewMode As Long

    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    'We use the ActiveSheet but you can replace this with
    'Sheets("MySheet")if you want
    With ActiveSheet

        'We select the sheet so we can change the window view
        .Select

        'If you are in Page Break Preview Or Page Layout view go
        'back to normal view, we do this for speed
        ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
        ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView

        'Turn off Page Breaks, we do this for speed
        .DisplayPageBreaks = False

        'Set the first and last row to loop through
        Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
        lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

        'We loop from Lastrow to Firstrow (bottom to top)
        For Lrow = lastrow To Firstrow Step -1

            'We check the values in the A column in this example
            With .Cells(Lrow, "A")

                If Not IsError(.Value) Then

                    If Not IsError(Application.Match(.Value, _
                    Sheets("BUSINESS_KEYWORDS").Range("A1:A683"), 0)) Then .EntireRow.Delete
                    'This will delete each row with the Value "ron"
                    'in Column A, case sensitive.

                End If

            End With

        Next Lrow

    End With

    ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With

End Sub
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if a string contains another instead of being exactly the same as the other then use this function:

```
If InStr(1, StringToBeSearched, StringtoFind, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    Do xyz
End If
```

`Instr` returns an integer representing the character at which the `StringToFind` appears in the `StringToBeSearched` and returns `0` if it cannot be found.